# Confused about declarations vs definitions in C for functions and variables

Tags: c, function, variables

I'm trying to understand the difference between variable definition, variable declaration, function definition, and function declaration. For example, site A would say that:
`int var=10; /* declare and initialize */` while site B would say:
`int y=20;     /* global variable definition and initialization */` One is called a declarative and the other is called a definition. Why? Which one is the right one? And does initializing the variables make it a declaration or definition? Same thing with functions. There seems to be different rules for both functions vs variables and it's confusing me big time.

Comment: A simple search result contains acceptable answers to your question: https://www.google.com/search?q=c+function+declarations+vs+definition

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between a definition and a declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. You should search for your problem before you ask. Otherwise your question will be flagged as duplicate.

Comment: Just one final thing that needs to be answered I'm confused about. If I used an identifier like int x = 10, would that automatically make it declared or defined?

Comment: An important point to understand, which is not always brought out, is that declarations and definitions are not disjoint.  In fact, every object or function definition expressed in C source code is also a declaration of the object or function it defines.  And particularly relevant to this question, every object declaration that initializes the declared object *is* a definition of that object.

Comment: and there is the tentative definition which is only a declaration if followef by an explicit definition...